# Javascript method call with list

Tags: javascript

Is it correct to call a javascript method like this

```
 var flag = this.totalSubarrayLengths([ document.getElementsByTagName('ol'), document.getElementsByTagName('ul') ])

 var totalSubarrayLengths = function(container) {
        total = 0;

        for (var val in container) {
            var total += val.length;
        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: BTW, a `for...in` used against arrays will put the index in `val`, so you won't be able to do `val.length`....

Answer (score 3):

So in total, no.

- You try to call a function with `this` as keyword, which is a simple function and not a class. Please have a look to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).
- The variable, which should later contain the function, is hoisted, without content. Better is to use function statement `function fn() {...}`, instead of function expression `fn = function () {...}`, because the function statements are always hoisted, that means they are moved to the beginning of the program and the position in the code is irrelevant.
- In the function, `total` is for every loop declared, and that is in combination with `+=` `an unexpected token`.
- You have to use `val` as index for `container` for the count.

```js
var flag = totalSubarrayLengths([document.getElementsByTagName('ol'), document.getElementsByTagName('ul')])

function totalSubarrayLengths(container) {
    var total = 0, val;
    for (val in container) {
        total += container[val].length;
    }
    return total;
}
document.write('total: ' + flag);
```

```html
<ul><li>ul</li></ul>
<ol><li>ol</li><li>ol</li><li>ol</li><li>ol</li></ol>
```

Comment: Wrong. You quickly tossed a code to be the first to add an answer :)

Comment: No, I understand what shouldn't be done in SO. Mostly I prefer to be the last to add an answer, but give a valid and well-explained answer. Sometimes the marked as right answer isn't the one with more upvotes. BTW no one should add answer just to see how a number gets increased...